# How can I trace the source of an nginx 301 redirect?

Tags: nginx, redirect

I have a strange situation where a URL is being 301 redirected and it's not in my site config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.domain.com;

    ...etc
}
```

Curl request:

```
curl --head -iL www.domain.com
```

And response:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx
Date: Wed, 02 Nov 2016 08:35:57 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 178
Connection: keep-alive
Location: http://domain.com/
```

I can't find anywhere this could be redirected. I've tried enabling debug logging but can't see any detail in the logs when I make that request so not sure where to go from here.

I don't believe it's the application installed at the URL as the redirect is happening before that is hit.

Where can I track this down?

Comment: Have you restarted nginx? Check what IP address is for `www.domain.com`.

Comment: @AlexeyTen yes nginx has been restarted. What relevance does the IP have? both domain.com and www.domain.com resolve to the same IP.

Comment: What is the full nginx configuration?